# how to set width of spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner

how to set width of the spinner programatically ?

Comment: Do you mean the spinner in a web page, or a spinner widget? The android:layout_width attribute can be used for the standard spinner widget

Comment: i am not taking spinner from xml.. it creates lots of mess in r.java file but i am initializing spinner on .java file and then seeing it through by adding view in the tablelayout which is the only thing i have taken on the xml page... please suggest some property if their is any... thanx for replying

Comment: The question is real and is perfectly understandable. It should not have been closed.

Answer (score 2):

In your layout file

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:prompt="@string/my_spinner"
/>
```

would give the spinner a width of `200dip`.

Comment: i want to give width in java page. i am using xml page for table layout only... and in table layout i am adding spinner in java page... and their is no property like setwidth for spinner on java page... so please suggest something ....